# Hibernate slow when using IN clause - MySQL. The exact same query runs much faster when run from MySQLWorkbench

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

We have a simple table with about 30 columns. When running a simple IN clause with primary keys on the table, Hibernate takes a really long time to execute the query. However, when we run the exact same query in MySQLWorkbench it returns much faster. We see atleast a 10x difference.

enabling Hibernate session metrics shows the following

```
Session Metrics {
    10542 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    197875 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    76234640084 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Says 76.2 seconds executing using Hibernate. However the exact same query (retrieved from both Hibernate and MySQL slow query logs) executed on MySQLWorkbench shows an execution time of 0.071 seconds.

We tried using hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding but it didn't make any difference. Tried a few other things but nothing seems to work.

Hibernate code

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
String hql = "SELECT d FROM Document d WHERE d.ddmObjectId IN (:ids)";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);           
List<UUID> listOfUUIDs = List.of(UUID.fromString("0de14895-bf1e-11ec-a830-02c68fc6d6d6"),UUID.fromString("0de14db9-bf1e-11ec-a830-02c68fc6d6d6"));
query.setParameterList("ids",listOfUUIDs);
List<Document> objectList = query.list();
Iterator iterator = objectList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Document document = (Document) iterator.next();
    System.out.println(document.toString());
}
   tx.commit();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Get Hibernate to print out the actual SQL it's using, and make sure it really is the SQL you expected.

Comment: Yup, already did that, It is the exact SQL. That same SQL is also in the MySQL Slow query logs. I took that same SQL and ran it in the Workbench and it executes very fast.

Comment: Can we see the Hibernate code please?

Comment: workbench may be adding a limit 1000 implictly.  how many rows are found in hibernate?

Comment: @RobertBain Yes, It's part of a bigger app. I will post it shortly

Comment: @ysth only two rows are found. I am only specifying two primary key ids. Its clear from the MySQL Slow Query Log that when Hibernate sends the query, MySQL is doing a full table scan whereas when the query is run from the workbench its using the index

Comment: @RobertBain Added Hibernate code.

Comment: Ah the joy of comparing raw query execution with the execution in JPA (which includes, datasource management, mapping to objects, transactions etc.) and we expect them to be the same. So first you are comparing 2 different things and thus you will get different output. Without knowing your mapping, how you setup your Hibernate this will be impossible to answer. For starters your question is marked Spring and Spring Boot but the way you use it, clearly shows that you are working around those. So either it isn't related to Spring (Boot) or you are doing really weird things.

Comment: Can we see the `Document` class in its entirety please?

Comment: Does Hibernate have a mode where it "gets smart" and pre-loads the entire table?  How many rows in the entire table?

Comment: So, I solved this by forcing MySQL to use an index using the FORCE INDEX keyword.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason MySQL is not using the index for this particular query from Hibernate. So we used an index hint, FORCE INDEX keyword on the query

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html